# Random data appearing in bar plot at regular intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataset containing information related to COVID-19 data with `columns = ['total_cases', 'new_cases', 'date']`. The data increases monotonically with atleast no sudden spikes in new_cases in January month. The dataset can be found here: https://fnvuusdqoptinxntjrmodi.coursera-apps.org/edit/CovidIndiaData.csv with lots of columns out of which I use only  `['total_cases', 'new_cases', 'date']`.

First 10 days data is 0 for `'new_cases'` as shown in this image:
[image: First 10 rows of dataset]

I use this code to plot bar plot for `'date'` vs `'new_cases'`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
df = pd.read_csv("CovidIndiaData.csv", parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'])
df = df[['new_cases', 'total_cases']]
df.fillna(0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

ax.bar(df.index.values,
   df['new_cases'],
   color='purple')

ax.set(xlabel="Date",
   ylabel="New Cases",
   title="New Cases per day",
   xlim=["2020-01-01", "2020-07-18"])

date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

The final plot looks like this:
[image: Bar Plot]

The plot shows some spikes at 7th January ('01-07' on plot) where clearly in dataset the new_cases are 0. This is continued approximately after every one month interval.

Where does this data come from? How can I plot a correct graph for this data?

Comment: Looks like you have the month and day exchanged.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Seems like pandas used the default data format for parsing the first 12 entries in my dataset and then it realized what the actual data format was. For ex. while parsing '01-01-2020' the actual format is '%d-%m-%Y' but it used '%m-%d-%Y' only to realize observing the 13th entry that the data format is different. I specified the data format while parsing my csv and it gave me correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Davis Herring for pointing out my mistake.

In case anyone faces similar issue, the solution is to specify date format when your date isn't in standardized format.
What I did is:

```
mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y")
df = pd.read_csv("CovidIndiaData.csv", parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=mydateparser, index_col=['date'])
```